# Comparing the contents of 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I want to compare. On side A, it contains IPtables rules split up in separate columns.
Example output array A;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [num] => 1
            [pkts] => 0
            [bytes] => 0
            [target] => DROP
            [prot] => all
            [opt] => --
            [in] => *
            [out] => *
            [source] => 192.168.0.1/32
            [destination] => 192.168.0.2/32

        )
```

On side B, I also have an array. However, this one has a slight difference.

```
   [1] => Array
        (
            [num] => 2
            [pkts] => 0
            [bytes] => 0
            [target] => DROP
            [prot] => all
            [opt] => --
            [in] => *
            [out] => *
            [source] => 192.168.5.5/32
            [destination] => 192.168.6.6/32
            [id] => 7
        )
```

As you can see, Array B has another column. Column ID.

What I want to do is, compare these two from the eyes of A.

So,

A-->B        then I want to output the difference.

In the field I have array A filled with 3 rules, and Array B for example 4 rules.

Array A needs to look at Array B, then output what is **not in there.**

Array B needs to be a exact copy of Array A, so to speak.

What I've tried, is to use `array_diff`. However, I've found out that that doesn't work since there's an ID column in array B, always being the difference.

So essentially what I'm looking for is a modified array_diff that **doesn't** look at the ID column in Array B... how to achieve this?

Comment: Couldn't you just unset the ID column (make a copy prolly) and then use array diff on the array without the id?

Comment: Both arrays have column `id`.

Comment: @LucasHarada Oops sorry, went a bit crazy with pasting. Take a look now, edited to my situation.

Comment: @LucasHarada : yes, so you unset them for both, and then compare....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, you could either unset the id from the inner array via `unset` or write your own comparison function via `array_diff_uassoc`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php

Comment: I tried unset(userINPUT[10]) but the id field is still there.. am I doing this right?

Comment: I do not know how your array structure looks like so I cannot tell you how to reference your elements. It should be something like `unset($myArray[1]["ID"])`if your inner array with the ID key is at position 1 of your outer array.

Comment: Thanks Michael, `unset()` works now by adding an extra dimension.

Answer (score 2):

So where 's the problem?

```
$arr1 = new ArrayObject(array('a' => 'bla', 'b' => 'blubb'));
$arr2 = new ArrayObject(array('a' => 'bla', 'b' => 'blubb', 'id' => 7));
$ignore = new ArrayObject(array('id'));

function compare(ArrayObject $arr1, ArrayObject $arr2, ArrayObject $ignore = null) {
    if ($ignore !== null && $ignore->count()) {
        foreach ($ignore as $offset2Ignore) {
            if ($arr2->offsetExists($offset2Ignore)) {
                $arr2->offsetUnset($offset2Ignore);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr1 == $arr2;
}
```

What does the code shown above= First it uses the SPL ArrayObject instead of a simple array. Second we define the offsets, which have to be ignored in the second array. If we have to ignore an offset, wie iterate through the ignore items and unset the offset. After that wie compare the to arrays. If they are equal the funktion returns true ... otherwise false.

If you want to know the differences between to arrays, you can change the return value at the code above by using array_diff().

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility for what Michael Helwig did is to do the opposite.

Add an `id` field in the side A array an use the `array_diff_uassoc` function. If you need, just unset the added `id` field later.